# Objects Declared in One Header, unavailable in Another Header and Implmentation

Tags: iphone, xcode, class, object

In an iPhone XCODE project, on the left is explorer with classes, objects etc.

I made my app in MainView.h and MainView.m. Design is made in MainWindow.xib.

Now I want to add an accelerometer. I added code in myappViewController.h and .m. but when I want to use some object declared (for example some buttons, views etc) in MainView.h the compiler says they are undeclared. How to move theese declared objects from MainView.h to see them in myappViewController.h ?

Answer (score 0):

The position and groupings of files, frameworks, media etc in the `Files and Groups` panel has nothing to do with the location of the items on disk or their inclusion or linkage to other pieces of code. The `Files and Groups` panel is purely an organizational convenience for the programmer. The only part that has functional relevance is the target. Items included in a target build show up within the target. Otherwise the organization is arbitrary.

You include objects from one header in another by importing the first header into the second. In you case it would be:

in myappViewController.h

```
#import "MainView.h"
```

... now objects defined in MainView.h are known to myappViewController.

Comment: i made import You wrote. but when i try to run app it shows MainView.h - no such file or directory. i dont know why is happens becaus the file is at his place in directory.

Comment: Get Info on the MainView.h in the Files and Groups and check its target to make sure it has been added to the target you are building. Xcode can build multiple targets, each with different files, so each file must be added to a specific target. When you create a file in a project it should default to adding it to all targets but that can be accidentally unchecked. Open up the target in Files and Groups and see if the file is listed under the target.

Comment: ok, i found its not in target group. but i cannot add it. when i do "get info" > "targets" mainview.h is not checked but its greyed and i caoont add it. what to do?\

Comment: Remove the file from the project and then add it back in. Then it should add to project automatically. I would also recommend a `clean all` of the build.

Comment: i made what You wrote and nothing happend. MainView.h is not in the target. when adding file i checked add to target etc but its not there. its some bug or something?

Comment: i doscovered i cannot add any other H file into target, i made clean new one h and cannot add it also :(

Comment: ha, i doscovered now that i cannot add any file in any other project either. i made new empty project and cannot add H files for example to target. what is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I made a typo. You add the classes implementation file, the `.m` file to the target. The `.h` file has to be included in the project only which it will be if it shows in Files and Groups. Make sure you use `#import "MainView.h"` and not `#import <MainView.h>` the latter is for external libraries/frameworks

Comment: If you can put your project up somewhere I could download it and try to figure out what the problem is.